# How can I allow both floating-point and integer types but disallow bool in a template

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Say I have some numerical class, with a constructor that allows a "number" (quotes on purpose).
Inside, it is stored as a floating-point value, so I want only a number as argument, so I denied instanciation on other types than floating-points:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyClass
{
   MyClass( T value ) : _v(value)
   {
      static_assert( std::is_floating_point<T>::value, "only numbers!" );
   }
   double _v;
};
```

However, this is annoying, because I always have to write `MyClass m(42.);` and sometimes I forget, or whatever, and I want to be able to write just `MyClass m(42);`.
So I added integral types:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyClass
{
   MyClass( T value ) : _v(value)
   {
      static_assert( std::is_floating_point<T>::value || std::is_integral<T>::value, "only numbers!" );
   }
   double _v;
};
```

The downside of this is that [std::is_integral](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) also allows `bool`.
And I feel that allowing automatic conversion from a boolean value to a numerical value is complete nonsense (in that situation of course).

```
MyClass m(true);  // no way !
```

Question: how can I allow both floating-point and integer types, and disable boolean type? (No `std::is_boolean` available)

Comment: Aside: `std::is_arithmetic<T>::value` means the same as `std::is_floating_point<T>::value || std::is_integral<T>::value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check `bool` with `std::is_same`. E.g.

```
MyClass( T value ) : _v(value)
{
   static_assert( ( std::is_floating_point<T>::value || 
                    std::is_integral<T>::value ) && 
                  !std::is_same<T, bool>::value, "only numbers!" );
}
```

Comment: Ah! thanks, yeah, I was looking into tweaking something with `std::integral_constant` but this fits nicely.

Comment: @kebs technically all those are integral constants aka specializations derived from true_type and false_type. You can roll out your own is_boolean if you need it more than one time.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the simplest way is template constructor + explicitly deleted constructor for `bool`. Take a look at this - it is pretty explicit and does what you want:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct MyClass
{
    template<class U>
    MyClass(U value) : _v(value)
    {
    }

    MyClass(bool) = delete;

   double _v;
};

int main() {
    auto foo = MyClass<double>(3);
    auto bar = MyClass<int>(1);
    auto baz = MyClass<double>(true); // fails
}
```

Comment: What about `MyClass<bool>(0)`?

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather keep a single constructor (actually, the class already has multiple others...).

Comment: This breaks automatic type deduction and requires you to give the type explicitly.